# If statement outputting both arguments instead of either?

Tags: ios, json, swift, if-statement, uiswitch

I have the following code but instead of outputting either of the statements; both statements are output:

EDITED:

**After a lot of trial and error I am still no closer to a solution, I have condensed my code down to just the bare minimum and removed all other controls in an attempt to solve this and still not working, here is my minimal code that is attached to a simple single switch:**

//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {


    let switchOn = mySwitch.isOn
    let endpoint = "http://10.0.1.147/setpins"
    let urlString = endpoint + "?D2=" + (switchOn ? "0" : "1023")

    mySwitch.setOn(!switchOn, animated:true)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

    }
    task.resume()

}


}
```

BUT:   Still getting the output of each argument output at the same time..

```
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17402d9e0> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/setpins?D1=0 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })

response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17002c8a0> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/setpins?D2=1023 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
```

Comment: Also please note that the outputs are reversed depending on On or Off

Comment: your question is unclear . could you share more detail ?

Comment: Nazmul, what I am saying is that the if then else statement above outputs both the arguments instead of just the if or the else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `if`-`else` in that case. Here is your completely rewritten code - try to run it and see if duplication issue goes away.

```
let switchOn = mySwitch.isOn
switchState.text = switchOn ? "OFF" : "ON"
let endpoint = "http://10.0.1.147/setpins"
let urlString = endpoint + "?D2=" + (switchOn ? "0" : "1023")

mySwitch.setOn(!switchOn, animated:true)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil else {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    // You can print out response object
    print("response = \(response)")

}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `task.resume` out of the `if..else` block along with other declarations.

```
//declare other variables here
if .... {
    ...
    ...
    ...
} else {
    ...
    ...
}

 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { 
     (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
         if error != nil{
             print("error=\(error)")
             return
         }
         // You can print out response object
         print("response = \(response)")
 }
 task.resume()
```

Comment: Will not work – `task` is declared in `if`-`else` scope so won't be visible outside.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz True. But it should work if all the declarations are moved to outside the scope of if-else

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tried but to no avail, in fact now it sends 3 message blocks

Comment: I cannot move any part of the statement to outside the if procedure as it cannot find the required parameters to output the http request.

Comment: @AndrewBrierley AlexanderDoloz's answer is better. Worked for me. You don't actually need a if-else block

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz Hi Alexander, I changed to your improved code but the end result is the same :-(  Please see the new screenshot and edited question in my original post,

Comment: @AndrewBrierley: 1. Try to put breakpoint on line `print("response = \(response)")` and check if app stopped here more than once. 2. Double-check that rest of your app code doesn't hit the same endpoint at the same time.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz  The app does stop here more than once. The same line is in the app in other place but not under the same procedure block?

Comment: @AndrewBrierley: check your IBActions in Interface Builder. It is possible that 1 button click produces 2 action handler calls.

Comment: I put in multiple break points and the problem is as if the code is in a loop and goes through the same procedure twice but for the life of me I am unable to identify the cause.....

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz I condensed the code to just yours essentially and then removed all other controls except the switch in question and it is still putting out both arguments...

Comment: I created a new project and started with just the switch and your code above @AlexanderDoloz, same result.  I can't understand why such a seemingly simple task of doing one thing with switch on and another with it off is so difficult? Is Swift always so hard?

Comment: @AndrewBrierley Good to see someone working so hard to solve a problem. Try using the debugger and use stepover with breakpoints. It becomes easier to know which parameter is causing the problem.

Comment: @AndrewBrierley: nope, Swift is not that difficult :) Looks like for some reason you call the code twice. Do you have handler on switch value change? Make sure your IBAction code is called only once.

Comment: Still no luck with this, I have tried all suggestions and spent way too many hours on it, so unless someone can tell me why it sends both arguments I am giving up. Will stick to separate on and off buttons which works well, just not as pretty..  Thank you Alexander, for spending so much time trying to help me.